# Angular in Visual Page - Salesforce

Tags: angularjs, salesforce

I would like to place angular controllers/components inside the Visual Page(VF page) of SalesForce. Whether it's a good practice or not?.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The use of AngularJs is encouraged here :
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics/units/lex_dev_lc_basics_intro

Comment: Actually, if you read that link, it is not encouraged, it is compared to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AngularJS with Visualforce, however, I would not try with Lightning Components.
Here is a blog post I found that describes how.
[AngularJS with Visualforce](http://www.algoworks.com/blog/develop-salesforce-visualforce-apps-using-angularjs/)